# my website on Google Adsense is not getting approved "No content"

Tags: adsense

I have a small script in my website with a good amount of traffic, but my website on Google Adsense is not getting approved "No content"? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:

> Anything less than about forty content-based pages is considered
>   'under construction' by Adsense, or - sometimes - 'no content'.
>   Another reason for this rejection is pages that are mainly images
>   rather than text. ... If you have mostly images or videos, that's 'no
>   content' as far as Adsense is concerned.

Comment: I have seen this explanation with the google support but my website has a few options to be used by the visitor, not much content so should i add some fake posts to fill my website?

Comment: Adding "fake" posts would likely be a violation of the Adsense terms and conditions.